# Cannot use auto-completion function in coc.nvim

Tags: configuration, neovim, godot, gdscript, coc.nvim

Whenever I enter a certain auto-completion suggestions from coc.nvim, it just flashes the suggestion and removes it entirely and it throws an error 'coc.nvim: command not found'. The suggestion tab shows normally and acts normally.

This bug always happens in a gdscript file, all other files work as intended.

I can't find a fix for this, maybe its the language server or the coc configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your init.vim file.

inoremap   complete_info().selected != -1 ?
\ &filetype == "gdscript3" ? (coc#expandable() ?  "<C-y>" : "<C-y>a") : "<C-y>"
\ : "<C-g>u<CR>"

Comment: Thanks for your addition to the list of answers. A terse explanation of what each of these macros does might be helpful to new users.